# PostgreSQL, Inserting floats with libpq

Tags: c, postgresql-9.1

I created insert string with mixed data in C and can't inserting rows.
As I can see problem may be in floats which in my locale uses comma as decimal separator.

So, when inserting I get error message:

> ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
>   LINE 1: ...0:11:37.097203 +0100', 'Book about solving issues', '', 'PCS', 0,000000)

Code for inserting:

```
 snprintf(sqlInsert, sizeof(sqlInsert), "INSERT INTO mytable (dtbl_id, kni, dtmp, iname, tagname, mea, klc) VALUES 
 (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %f)", o, k, dt, es, tagname, meas)), IL.klc);
```

How to solve this situation to properly insert double precision numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rc = snprintf(sqlInsert, sizeof sqlInsert
, "INSERT INTO mytable (dtbl_id, kni, dtmp, iname, tagname, mea, klc)"
" VALUES               (%d,     '%s', '%s', '%s',  '%s',   '%s', %f);"
                       , o,      k,    dt,   es, tagname, meas, IL.klc);
```

UPDATE: if there are locale problems, setlocale() might help you to set the local inside your program. LC_ALL=POSIX (or C) should always be present. (it could well be that one of the {%e %f %g} formats is insensitive to the locale settings)

The following program demonstrates the use of setlocale():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#pragma DONT define DEFAULT_LOCALE "POSIX"
#define DEFAULT_LOCALE "nl_NL.utf8"
/* LC_NUMERIC LC_ALL */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double val;
    char *old, *new;

    val = 1024 * 1024;
    val /= 10;

    printf ("Original: Val=%f\n", val);
    new = argv[1] ? argv[1] : DEFAULT_LOCALE ;

    old = setlocale (LC_ALL, new );

    printf("Old=%s, New=%s\n", old, new );
    printf ("After change: Val=%f\n", val);

    new = setlocale (LC_ALL, old );

    printf("Old=%s, New=%s\n", new,  old);
    printf ("After restore: Val=%f\n", val);
return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
plasser@pisbak:./a.out
Original: Val=104857.600000
Old=nl_NL.utf8, New=nl_NL.utf8
After change: Val=104857,600000
Old=nl_NL.utf8, New=nl_NL.utf8
After restore: Val=104857,600000
plasser@pisbak:
```

After reading the manuals I expected setlocale() to return the old setting, but that does not seem to be the case.  Maybe I unintentionally  changed some global setting :-[

UPDATE: It is always good to explicitely cast arguments to *printf() functions.

```
#include <locale.h>
(void) setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX" );

rc = snprintf(sqlInsert, sizeof sqlInsert
, "INSERT INTO mytable (dtbl_id, kni, dtmp, iname, tagname, mea, klc)"
" VALUES               (%d,   '%s', '%s', '%s',   '%s',  '%s', %f);"
                  , (int) o,     k,   dt,   es, tagname, meas, (double) IL.klc);
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work. It is odd to talk about locales when we talk about numbers anyway. Almost whole Europe uses comma as decimal separator so I'm wonder now how people do this. OK, I can convert doubles to strings and store them like strings but then I have strings in database not numbers what is for most cases totally unacceptable.

Comment: Did you fix the `))', too? What does the buffer contain after the snprintf() ? BTW, in my case it appeared that the locale was not applied to the libc-stuff. The manual pages indicated that there has been different standard behaviour in older versions.

Comment: Yes, I fix. IL.klc is 8 bit number readen from file. If I do printf("%f\n", IL.klc); I get 0,000000. Same is in the buffer. And same with MySql which works with numbers well. If I write number back to file it will be packed again to 8 bits no matter of what is my decimal sign. So I thought that PQ will store my number in binary way. I still think that I do something wrong because storing numbers is so basic operation for such huge system as PQ is and that it shouldn't be connected to locales.

Comment: It is a good habit to cast arguments to printf(). (and other varargs functions)

Comment: Yes, with (void) setlocale (LC_ALL, "POSIX" ); 'thing' works as expected but now is question how would this be related to my national sorting specifics. Also to collations, filtering text and similar. Also, setting locales before query and restoring after it sounds bit overdressed. Maybe here is some setting on my server which can be switched to my locale?

Comment: Yes, I feel your pain. I 'don't like to tinker with these things, mainly because collation sequences, encoding and date formats are probably affected, too. You could try to use LC_NUMERIC instead of LC_ALL as 1st argument to setlocale(). Just to minimise the damage...

Comment: After first complex tests I see that everything works fine :) Better than expected. Collations and sortings are propper to my locale. In windows I must choose C locale instead of POSIX. After using writable queries I simply change back with this: (void) setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); Is this correct? After all, thank you VERY MUCH for concrete help!